# Cauchy root test for periodic functions

Tags: limits

This issue has been on my mind for a few days;
What is the outcome of the cauchy root test, let's say for $a_n = sin(n)$?
It is obvious that it's probably 1, or else there would be a limit to this function.
What I don't understnand, is why we can assume that the limit 
$$lim_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n] {\lvert sin(n)\rvert}$$
exists.

Comment: it doesn't, the test involves this limit when it exists, when it doesn't it involves $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$. and you should go back first to the definition of the radius of convergence : the $R$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n $ converges when $|z| < R$ and diverges when $|z| > R$. this way it is obvious that if $|a_n| < C$ and $|a_n|\not \to 0$ then the radius of convergence is $R=1$

Comment: Thank you, Such a simple reason! I don't know how I overlooked it.

Comment: @OlivierOloa : but I think there is a problem with wikipedia/radius_over_convergence since it is very unclear for many people who ask about this test

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thank you, Ive added an absolute value so the function will be defined for each n.

Comment: or the problem is with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Radius_of_convergence because https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence is quite good. Yonatan did you read wiki/Radius_of_convergence ? or only wiki/Power_series ?